# Convert *.pem certs into mozilla certdata.txt

Tags: security, ssl, https, mozilla

There is numbers of tools that converts certdata.txt from [here](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/tip/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt) into .pem format again. However I would need to do it the opposing way: create certadata.txt from a given .pem or .der file.

Does anyone knows a tool that converts *.pem certs into the certdata.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting a closer look of nss-tools I have found what I really needed:

nss-addbuiltin:

*Read a der-encoded cert from certfile or stdin, and output
   it to stdout in a format suitable for the builtin root module.
   Example: **nss-addbuiltin -n MyCA -t "C,C,C" -i myca.der >> certdata.txt***

Answer (score 0):

The file you referenced is a definition file. You generally never feed it directly to an application, instead you convert the certdata.txt into a list of certificates in `.pem` format.

This is what most of consumers fo:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.security.policy/J7mY_cpOyX4
- http://curl.haxx.se/cvssource/lib/mk-ca-bundle.pl
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42946/where-can-i-find-all-ssl-ca-certificates

If you use the PEM list, then it's just as simple as adding your certificate to the end of that list.

Comment: yes, we also don't use the certdata.txt directly but use it to generate our rootstore. However, what I need is the opposite of mk-ca-bundle